# Use session_id from Salesforce to authenticate?

Tags: python, oauth, salesforce

I'd like to be able to make api call from Salesforce to Python, and then upload some data back in Salesforce asynchronously. Therefore, I need to login as the original user in Salesforce to process my actions. For instance, an api call is made from SF to Python, and then I'd like to create an account from Python.

I use simple-salesforce in Python.

I'm passing the session_id from the UserInfo.getSessionId() from Salesforce as a header in my api call to Python, but then I'm unable to use simple-salesforce to act as the originating user.

How should I do so ?

I've tried the following, but I always get an invalid session_id error.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce    
Salesforce(instance_url="https://cs128.salesforce.com", session_id=session_id)
    Salesforce(instance_url="https://cs128.salesforce.com", session_id=session_id, domain='test')
    Salesforce(instance="test.salesforce.com", session_id=session_id, domain='test')
    Salesforce(instance="test.salesforce.com", session_id=session_id)
```

In my test, the user has a profile of system admin, with api enabled. Using my user with login/password I can succesfully login to Salesforce so no problem on this side.

Just looking for a way to use the session_id from salesforce to keep on acting as the originating user.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest passing both the instance domain and the session_id to your Python app. Do you use My Domain? If so, you could potentially have a mismatch between session id and domain. You might try using your My Domain url (something.my.salesforce.com) instead of "cs128.salesforce.com" just to check.

I suspect that URL.getOrgDomainUrl() could be your friend.

Have you tried a Visualforce page to output the session ID, just for testing?

```html
<apex:page >
    <dl style="font-size: 1.5rem">
        <dt>Session Id:</dt>
        <dd><code>{!$Api.Session_ID}</code></dd>
    </dl>
</apex:page>
```

I usually use something like this:

```py
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

connection = Salesforce(
    instance="cs128.salesforce.com",
    session_id="00D60000000AbCd!AQUARGttOODucvVr2UcfSa4OB5KU_.zniNMrNMj361Sbr1ZIPKI7V6g_qNJBWJWFdsoO1Kf0ui5OYFw_jX0J1AFlyDL0sOnz",
    version="48.0"
)
```

(That session_id is not real, but yours should look very similar.)

One other way to get the session ID, at least for testing: your browser cookies. Specifically, the `sid` cookie. Just make sure you pull it from the same domain you are calling from Python.

Hope something here helps!

Edit: I have since written about three ways to obtain domain and Session ID in [an article titled "Obtain Salesforce Session Id through Visualforce, Anonymous Apex, or Cookie Retrieval](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/3-ways-to-obtain-salesforce-session-id-visualforce-anonymous-apex-and-cookie-retrieval-h0m).